# How to use Logic App tolower() function

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, tolower

Using the below code as a sample (there would be way more results), I am constructing an if true/false statement that will have the input as either upper or lower case. I am unsure how to utilise the tolower() function that will force the input to always be lower case for the statement.

```
[
    {
        "VM":  "MyVM1",
        "Success":  true,
        "PSComputerName":  "localhost",
        "PSShowComputerName":  true,
        "PSSourceJobInstanceId":  "5e18cd92-5676-4ed6-a7e4-14b0d9fea3b3"
    },
    {
        "VM":  "MyVM2",
        "Success":  true,
        "PSComputerName":  "localhost",
        "PSShowComputerName":  true,
        "PSSourceJobInstanceId":  "5e18cd92-5676-4ed6-a7e4-14b0d9fea3b3"
    }
]
```

My logic app flow:
[image]

My preferred logic app flow alteration:
[image: flow]

As you can see, I have tried using the condition as follows:

```
@contains(tolower(items('For_each')['VM'], 'myvm1'))
```

However I am presented with the following error output when the logic app is run:

> InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions for
>   action 'Condition' at line '1' and column '2179': 'The template
>   language function 'tolower' expects one parameter: the string to
>   convert to lower casing. The function was invoked with '2' parameters.
>   Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#toLower for usage
>   details.'.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language

I have looked at the documentation, but sadly I don't understand it enough to know how to edit this query. Any help would be greatly apprec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So...the error is correct.  Your current expression

> @contains(tolower(items('For_each')['VM'], 'myvm1'))

is passing two parameters to tolower()

@contains(tolower(**items('For_each')['VM'], 'myvm1'**))

items('For_each')['VM'] --and-- 'myvm1'

Maybe you really want

> @contains(tolower(items('For_each')['VM']), 'myvm1')

Comment: using that expression didn't cause an error this time, however it still couldn't find `MyVM1`. i changed the code to have `MyVM1` in capitals to see if i would get anything, but it still couldn't find it:  `@contains(tolower(items('For_each')['VM']), 'MyVM1')`

Comment: Actually, you were right. Thanks. I had setup the following actions to be incorrect, which is why I couldn't see the result.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @John-305 is correct. You have parenthesis issue with you statement. 
The Correct statement is:

> "@contains(tolower(items('For_each')['VM']), 'myvm1')"

Try this logic app for reference:

```js
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Condition": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Append_to_array_variable": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "result",
                                    "value": "@items('For_each')"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                            }
                        },
                        "expression": "@contains(tolower(items('For_each')['VM']), 'myvm1')",
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "If"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Parse_JSON')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "result",
                            "type": "Array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": [
                        {
                            "PSComputerName": "localhost",
                            "PSShowComputerName": true,
                            "PSSourceJobInstanceId": "5e18cd92-5676-4ed6-a7e4-14b0d9fea3b3",
                            "Success": true,
                            "VM": "MyVM1"
                        },
                        {
                            "PSComputerName": "localhost",
                            "PSShowComputerName": true,
                            "PSSourceJobInstanceId": "5e18cd92-5676-4ed6-a7e4-14b0d9fea3b3",
                            "Success": true,
                            "VM": "MyVM2"
                        }
                    ],
                    "schema": {
                        "items": {
                            "properties": {
                                "PSComputerName": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "PSShowComputerName": {
                                    "type": "boolean"
                                },
                                "PSSourceJobInstanceId": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "Success": {
                                    "type": "boolean"
                                },
                                "VM": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            },
                            "required": [
                                "VM",
                                "Success",
                                "PSComputerName",
                                "PSShowComputerName",
                                "PSSourceJobInstanceId"
                            ],
                            "type": "object"
                        },
                        "type": "array"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Response": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": "@variables('result')",
                    "statusCode": 200
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Response"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}
```